# Running "google-chrome" on WSL Ubuntu as --headless --no sandbox gives multiple errors - how do I take screenshot using headless in WSL?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, google-chrome-headless

I'm running Windows 10 and I have been using an Ubuntu Linux distro under the Windows Linux Subsystem.

I want to be able to use Chrome.exe or google-chrome to run headless and take screenshots, generate pdfs etc... as part of library calls, but can't see to do that (e.g. to use jupyter_to_medium library launches chrome in the background to take screenshot).

I have tried multiple things to debug it with google-chrome independently of the library or programme I'm using.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I **can** launch Chrome (Windows executable) via the Ubuntu terminal, having redirected it to the Windows executable:

   ```
   /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
   ```

   When I do that, a new tab opens in my Windows Chrome browser so no issues here.
2. When I try to use `google-chrome` headless in ubuntu terminal I get **MULTIPLE ISSUES** e.g.

   2a) Trying to get a screenshot - **FAILs** showing `Network service crashed, restarting service` endless loop - had to CTRL^C to stop it

   ```
    (base) etzimopoulos@DESKTOP-HI9P6E4:~$ google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
   [0626/055458.471044:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(61)] Failed to enable receiving udev events.
   [0626/055458.612113:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(262)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
   [0626/055458.696014:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(262)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
   ...
   ```

   2b) Trying to get a screenshot using a **different parameters** `--no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox` , getting different error this time.

   ````
   $ sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --headless --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
   [0626/061854.348849:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(61)] Failed to enable receiving udev events.
   [0626/061855.311675:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(46)] Descriptor access mode (0) differs from expected (2)
   [0626/061855.312483:WARNING:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(366)] Could not translate tid - assuming crashing thread is thread group leader; syscall_supported=0
   [0626/061855.474617:WARNING:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(366)] Could not translate tid - assuming crashing thread is thread group leader; syscall_supported=0
   --2020-06-26 06:18:55--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
   Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 216.58.210.46, 2a00:1450:4009:800::200e
   Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|216.58.210.46|:443... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [0626/061855.655013:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(399)] Abnormal renderer termination.
   429 Too Many Requests
   2020-06-26 06:18:55 ERROR 429: Too Many Requests.


   Unexpected crash report id length
   Failed to get crash dump id.
   Report Id: ```
   ````
3. Trying to run the **Windows executable Chrome.exe** with same parameters, seems to run but not screenshot is being taken (no new files in my directory)
4. Trying to run `google-chrome` **without** elevated privilages in WSL I get a different error:

   `google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/ Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied Failed to generate minidump.Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

Any help or direction would be hugely appreciated. My other option would be to run a VM on windows 10 with native Linux UI and terminal, which would probably work.

But is there a way to have it all setup in WSL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this (tested in wsl2)

In your wsl2 ubuntu console enter the following commands:

```
#install packages
sudo apt-get install -y curl unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4 fonts-liberation
#get latest chrome
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

#install it
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

#test a screenshot
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: It is not working to me: WSL2 Ubuntu:
1124/141516.139879:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1124/141516.139982:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1]    6863 trace trap  google-chrome

Comment: @AlejandroSanzDíaz this seems like you cannot start google chrome, and there is a bug open for google chrome to fix it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1228625 my suggestion is to try a known working version of chrome instead of stable_current some users reported google-chrome-stable=93.0.4577.82-1 is working fine so try this version http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_93.0.4577.82-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Thank you @Jinxmcg. Looks like, as in the bug comments is reported, using --disable-gpu solves the issue.

Comment: In the code I posted as initial answer the last line recommended using --headless and --disable-gpu as parameters to google chrome

Comment: see this answer for ways to install specific versions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590412/402487

Comment: In addition, I would suggest u to use the `no-sandbox` argument as well as use the suitable version as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588767/running-google-chrome-on-wsl-ubuntu-as-headless-no-sandbox-gives-multiple#comment123941166_65992939 and download the chromedriver accordingly e.g. download older version https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.82/ if u plan to use it with chromedriver